# How to make matplotlib colorbar inner ticks visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis, colorbar

I want to make a colorbar that would have its tick pointing inward. However, when I set the direction of ticks to 'in', the ticks are draw beneath the colorbar and are almost invisible. What should I do to make them drawn on top of the colorbar?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

norm = plt.Normalize(0, 100)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="Purples", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(sm)

cbar.outline.set_visible(False)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20, color='k')
```

gives (outer ticks visible): 
[image: outer ticks]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

norm = plt.Normalize(0, 100)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="Purples", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(sm)

cbar.outline.set_visible(False)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20, color='k', direction='in')
```

gives (inner ticks invisible):
[image: inner ticks]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you create a [mcve] and include the version of matplotlib you are using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. For me ticks are shown correctly. A [mcve] is needed here.

Comment: Corrected, now it's Complete

Comment: Running your code gives [this resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhucz.png), where the ticks are visible as expected. Note that a verifiable example also needs to include information about the system used to run the code, i.e. version of software in use, way to run the code etc.

Comment: On my laptop, it gives the image above with the ticks not visible. I'm running it in a Jupyter Notebook with ```%matplotlib inline```, can it be the problem?

Comment: [Running in Juypter notebook with `%matplotlib inline`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5YSZ.png).

Comment: Oh, I got it now, it was seaborn that I also imported in the same environment that was creating problems. When I restarted my kernel, the problem was gone. Thank you!